# Solving complex eqautions

Tags: complex-numbers

I have an equation:

$\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{z^4+8}=-i$

I have no idea where to begin solving this! My book doesn't seem to give any hints on equations like this. How do I solve it and what can I search for on information on this? Roots of complex numbers...? Complex equations? I'm just not sure.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both sides by $z^4+8$?

Comment: Yes. I'm still unsure what is being asked. I have't solved complex equations before.

Comment: Should I solve for Z?

Comment: What you're asked is to find the extension of the set $\left\{z\in \mathbb C\colon \dfrac{8\sqrt{3}}{z^4+8}=-i\right\}$. Do you understand this'

Comment: No. I don't understand what you mean by 'extension' of the set.

Comment: See the [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(semantics)) wikipedia entry. As an example, the extension of the set $\{x\in \mathbb R\colon x^2=1\}$ is $-1,1$.

Answer (score 2):

$8\sqrt{3}=-i(z^4+8) \to 8\sqrt{3}i=(z^4+8) \to z^4 =8\sqrt{3}i-8$

Now you should $8\sqrt{3}i-8$ represent this in polar cordinates $r*e^{i \alpha}$

Comment: How does $8\sqrt{3}=-i(z^4+8)$ become $8\sqrt{3}i=(z^4+8)$ ?

Comment: @PazeMultiply by $i$ on both sides.

Comment: Right, the number i behaves differently than others of course..

Comment: Not differently at all.

Comment: No, but you know what I mean. With any other variable, if you multiply by that variable, the equation wouldn't end up like that.

Comment: So I've got:

$z^4=16 \left( \frac{1}{2}- \frac {\sqrt{3} }{2} \cdot i \right)$

But I'm unsure how I continue!

Comment: You need to think about z as $z=re^{i\alpha}$

Comment: How do you solve $z^3=1$ ? is the same